# How To Add Variable To Const in C#

Tags: c#

I have CONST and I want to make this CONST equal variable I made ,I know the value of CONST doesn't changed by default but if any way to do that ,Is it Valid in C# to  do this or not?

I am Searching but I doesn't found solution..

Comment: No, that's why it's called constant. If you want to have it variable, use a variable. But maybe I don't understand your use case.

Comment: `I doesn't found solution`  a solution to *what* problem? Whatever the real problem is, modifying a constant won't solve it. A constant is exactly what the name says and the compiler is free to assume it will never change. This means the compiler is free to use the actual value everywhere it's needed instead of trying to read it from a specific location and store it in the executable itself instead of a memory location. Even if you modified one of those locations the value would be unchanged in all other locations

Comment: Did you try changing a constant that's used by other assemblies, and found this had no effect? It's precisely because a constant isn't expected to ever change. You'll have to recompile those assemblies to get them to use the new "constant". The alternative is to use a `public static readonly` value

Comment: @rotabor a *lot* of people, because a) it doesn't describe the real problem and b) this is a basic question answered many times.

Comment: @rotabor this is clearly an [X/Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Modifying a const is obviously wrong and the OP knows that. What really needs to be understood is _what_ the OP is trying to do that lead them down that path.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, you cannot set the value of a variable to a constant (const).

*A constant expression is an expression that can be fully evaluated at compile time.*

Read more:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const

Comment: "you cannot set the value of a const to a variable." -> the other way round, "set the value of a variable to a constant (const)"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that, use a read-only property:

*atype* MyProp() { get; init; }

You can initialize it in the constructor by desired value including that is gotten from a variable but will not be able to change it later.

Considering Panagiotis's comment, the solution above creates the instance-scoped constant. To create the class-scoped constant, use:

static readonly *atype* MyField;

Comment: The equivalent is a `static readonly`, not a read-only property that may change from one object instance to the next